# Parse date with "America/New_York" like time zones

Tags: java, date, parsing, timezone

Trying to parse a date with a detailed time zone:

```
var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
sdf.parse("2022-09-02 02:30:10 America/New_York");
```

Getting:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2022-09-02 02:30:10 America/New_York"
```

Tried: specifying "z", "zzz", "X" and "XXX" in the date formatter.

Comment: Are you able to use the more modern java.time package instead of `SimpleDateFormat`? That would be *much* better in general, and with `DateTimeFormatter` you can use the `V` symbol for time zone ID.

Comment: I too strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the modern Time API with a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead. The symbol for a (long) Zone-id is `VV`.

For example

```
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(
                         "2022-09-02 02:30:10 America/New_York", 
                         DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV")));
```

Outputs

```
2022-09-02T02:30:10-04:00[America/New_York]
```